# why is my loop of cubed digits producing incorrect outputs?

Tags: python, loops

I am having issue with the output of my code below:

```
m=10
total_n = 0
n = 1
while n <= m // 2:
    for i in range(0, n):
        total_n += (n - i) ** 3
    n += 1
    print(total_n)
```

For some reason, the output is 1,10,46,146,371.

But when I write it out on paper it should be 1,9,36,100,225.

Any idea which part of the code is not quite right? Cheers

Comment: Could you share the question? I'm having a hard time what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the proper result you want, just initialize `total_n` inside the first loop (see code below). The way you are doing it, `total_n` keeps track of all the sums but seems you only want the sum for each `n`.

```
m = 10
n = 1

while n <= m // 2:
  total_n = 0
  
  for i in range(0, n):
    total_n += (n - i) ** 3

  n += 1
  print(total_n)
```